# fazer rows serem links no php

Tags: php, html, sql

Boa Noite, tenho um banco de dados e nele duas colunas, uma de Links e a outra de nomes, esses links são para páginas com mais informações sobre o filme, e a coluna nome contém os nomes dos filmes, pois bem, quero que meu site liste os filmes pelos nomes e esses nomes serem links para as páginas, já tentei tudo que meu conhecimento permite, o que é bem pouco, espero que me ajudem.

```
$query = "SELECT paginas, Nome FROM links_paginas_filmes";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    foreach($row as $field => $value) {
        if($field != 'paginas') continue;
        echo ('<a href="Black-Mirror.html">' . $value . '</a>');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Algo nessa linha:

```
$query = "SELECT paginas, Nome FROM links_paginas_filmes";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
   echo '<a href="'.urlencode($row['paginas']).'">'.htmlentities($row['Nome']).'</a>';
}
```

A variável `$row` já retorna um *array* com o nome dos campos.

Usamos `htmlentities` para acertar caracteres especiais, como apóstrofos/plicas, aspas e outros no HTML.

Além disso, o endereço foi posto com `urlencode` no `href=""` por motivo similar. Tem casos em que você precisa desta construção:

```
htmlentities(urlencode($row['paginas']));
```

Entenda a diferença no manual do PHP:

> [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.urlencode.php)
>   [htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.htmlentities.php)
>   [htmlspecialchar()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

Comment: Sem chance cara, não aparece nada :(